# mysqld upgrade 5.5 -> 5.6 mysql Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

After updating mysql with yum to 5.6 I am getting such an error message when trying to run mysql

```
[root@host rpm]# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I also tried

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

and the result is the same.

Comment: How did you installed new and old MySQL (by using (yum or apt-get) or compressed file.)?

Comment: With yum. I suspect the update went wrong somewhere... I scrapped the entire virtual server, and rebuilt from scratch with the latest mysql, so the issue is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you are using correct root password. You can also use another login which has all privileges. Check it by logging to `mysql`:

[image]

Successful login example:

[image]

After checking return to server try again `mysql_upgrade`

Comment: Please post your code as text not as screenshots. Thanks!